# Convert Object to a List of Arrays

Tags: javascript

I am being passed a key/value object called obj that needs to convert to a list of arrays in an array ( arr[ [key: value] [key: value] ] )

```
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  var i = 0;
  for(var key in obj){
    arr[0][i][0] = key;
    arr[0][i][1] = obj[key];
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: You can't have `key:value` in an array. What are you really trying to get as the result? Show a sample input and (valid) output.

Comment: What is the problem? What is your target?

Comment: It looks like you will be receiving undefined errors in that loop as `arr[0]` is `undefined` (and so are each children `arr[0][i]` `arr[0][i][0]`) you would need to define them before you try to set their properties

Comment: ... `Object.entries(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and return a new object for each property.

```
function convertObjectToList(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).map(function (k) {
        var temp = {};
        temp[k] = object[k];
        return temp;
    });
}
```

ES6

```
function convertObjectToList(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign to indexes of an array element until you create the array element. Since there's no `arr[0]`, you can't assign to `arr[0][i]`. The solution is to iniialize the array with an inner array already in it.

For the third level, you can just use an array literal, you don't need to assign to indexes. And you can use `.push()` to add elements to an array, rather than incrementing `i`.

```
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  var arr = [[]];
  for(var key in obj){
    arr[0].push([key, obj[key]]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```